# How can I change the display of government field in drupal commerce shipping address?

Tags: commerce, entities

I need to change the display of the order/shipping address of drupal commerce to render the city in a select list instead of writing the city, I need to upload in the database the list of the cites relevant to the governments of Egypt.

Are there a module may help to achieve this? as I don't have a PHP developing experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a way to do this with the Address Field module. One of the Address Field maintainers has [addressed that this in the works](https://www.drupal.org/node/2185243) for 2.x release. In the meantime, the only way to do this is with a custom module. Someone has already [written up an example](http://mgalalm.com/2014/06/12/change-city-text-field-provide-by-addressfield-to-select-box/) of how to do this, specifically using Egypt as an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, i tested the code but it doesn't work with me, anyway i commented on it and i wish the author contacts me for clarification.